# Drupal hook_preprocess_HOOK

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

In my own module i can override successful `template_preprocess_region()` with

```
 function mymodule_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
   ...
 }
```

Described at [hook_preprocess_HOOK](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7)

Is there a possibility  to call a hook_preprocess_HOOK depending on an URl specified in hook_menu()?

Answer (score 0):

OK i can solve it with `current_path()` function.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
   if(current_path() == "mypath") {
     unset($variables['content']);
   }
}
```

I think it's not the best way. This way i have to duplicate all paths from hook_menu() ?! 
Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use drupal_match_path()
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_match_path/7

You can create a settings field for your path patterns.

Comment: OK, what did you mean exactly with SETTINGS FIELD? Is it right to say that it is just a other method to recieve the path in mymodule_preprocess_region()? It also works perfectly with current_path() above. My problem is, that i've defined some more paths in mymodule_menu, which i have to repeat know in the mymodule_preprocess_region func. Isn't there a drupalish way to specify a preprocess func just for one item in hook_menu or call a preprocess func manually in a other func? In my case i don't won't to call the preprocess func on every page, which happens without the if-clause.

Comment: Create a Drupal variable (variable_set) which contains all the path you need. Use this variable to create the menu items in hook_menu() (foreach?) and to check the path in _preprocess_region (or any other function). Use the drupal_match_path() to check if your current path matches to any path stored in your variable. I hope this make sense.